# What's the meaning of "have far to go"

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbs

I can't understand the meaning of "have far to go" in the sentence:

My heart rushes into my throat and although I know I don’t have far to go, I feel an overwhelming urge to look down on the city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be two possibilities:

1. *Far* as an adjective and is short for *a far way*: The word [*far*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/far) is not a noun. It is either adjective or adverb. "I know I don't have a far way to go."
2. *Far* as an adverb: "I know I don't have to go far" would be easier to understand, but the writer placed far between *have* and *to*. In this case, *far* reads more like a noun than an adverb.

Regardless of its part of speech, phrases like "have far to go" and "have long to go" are used even though *far* and *long* are not a *noun*. They are idiomatic expressions.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

**Have far to go** means you have **a long distance** you need to travel, it could also mean you **have a lot to do** on something you are working on

Your sentence says

> **don't have far to go**

which means **a short distance** or **almost finished**

> ...although I know I **don’t have far to go** ...
>
> ...*although I know I* ***only have a short distance***  *(on the ledge)* ... *I feel an urge to look down* ...
>   ...*although I know I'm* ***almost done*** ... *I feel an urge to look down ... (before I jump)*